# Using a defined global variable in a collection variable

Tags: postman

I have the following setup:

- A global variable `api_address` defined as `http://apiproduction.mydomain.com`.
- A collection variable `route_address` defined as `users/profiles` for each collection.

Right now my query look like: `{{api_address}}/{{route_address}}/004ba492-d021-40fe-ba23-f1d366036af4` if i want to get the resource.

So my question is... Could you include in a collection variable a global one?

Example: `{{route_address}}` could be defined as `{{api_address}}/users/profiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this! But you have to do it with pre-request scripts.
Edit your selection and go to the pre-request script tab.

Add something like the following:

```
let api_address = pm.globals.get("api_address");
pm.variables.set("route_address", `${api_address}/users/profile`);
```

That should give you your "route_address" that you are looking to variablize.
You can probably to the pm.globals.get inline on your set, but I'm old school and think it's cleaner and easier to read if you throw it into a local variable first.